# jQuery chosen scroll issue, element which contains the chosen doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am facing some issues with the jQuery Chosen plugin. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

The focused `Users` input is a jQuery Chosen `select` input within a tab in a Bootstrap dialog (but this doesn't matter anyway). As you can see the scroll of the Chosen's `ul.chosen-results` didn't reach the bottom here.

Now if I scroll down the results:

[image]

I reach the bottom of `ul.chosen-results`, but if scroll with the mouse wheel down further from this point on, the rightmost scroll doesn't scroll down.

But I would like the other scroll to go down too from that point on while scrolling down `ul.chosen-results` with the bottom scroll of `ul.chosen-results` reached, to achieve this:

[image]

See that the rightmost scrollbar is down here too. This is what I want to reach while scrolling on `ul.chosen-results`. Does Chosen somehow inhibit the scroll event propagation when scrolling `ul.chosen-results`?

Can I achieve what I want? How?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 6):

In the not minified js plugin file
find following code

`high_top = this.result_highlight.position().top + this.search_results.scrollTop();`

and replace it by this.

`high_top = this.result_highlight.position().top;`

This issues has been addressed [here](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2506) another possible fix is to update to jQuery 2.2.1

Comment: I tried your patch, however it doesn't seem to work, the scroll is bouncing down and up when I scroll and I cannot scroll to the bottom of the choices. I am using Chosen Version 1.5.1 and jQuery 1.11.2